# Conditional rendering inside form in React not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying for this component to show the specific form based upon the option select. I'm using the switch statement for conditional rendering. But at the moment it's not working, what am I missing?

```
class Form extends Component {
    state = {
            selectedValue: ''
        };
    handleChange(event) { 
        this.setState({selectedValue: event.target.value}); 
        }
    renderSelectedForm = (param) => {
        const formStyle = {
            display: 'none'
        }
        switch(param) {
            case 'form_name1':
            return <form name="form_name1" id="form_name1" style={formStyle}>
                    form 1
                    </form>;
            case 'form_name2':
            return <form name="form_name1" id="form_name2" style={formStyle}>
                    form 2
                    </form>;
            case 'form_name3':
            return <form name="form_name1" id="form_name3" style={formStyle}>
                    form 3
                    </form>;
            default:
            return null;
        }
    }

    render() {

        return (
             <div>
      <div className={styles.ContactUs}>
              <form >
                <select value={this.state.selectedValue} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                    <option value="form_name1">Form 1</option>
                    <option value="form_name2">Form 2</option>
                    <option value="form_name3">Form 3</option>
                </select>
             </form>
      {this.renderSelectedForm(this.state.selectedValue)}
    </div>
    </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Form;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a default value in your state for the first form to be shown, such as `form_name1`. Or add an option like 'Select a form' to your select element.

If you're doing conditional rendering, you don't really need to set `display: none` in your elements. Each element will be rendered according to your current state and `null`  is returned for unmounting the component.

```js
class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      selectedValue: 'form_name1'
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }

  handleChange(event) { 
    this.setState({selectedValue: event.target.value}); 
  }

  renderSelectedForm (param) {
    switch(param) {
      case 'form_name1':
        return (
          <form name="form_name1" id="form_name1">
            form 1
          </form>
         )
      case 'form_name2':
        return (
          <form name="form_name1" id="form_name2">
            form 2
          </form>
        )
      case 'form_name3':
        return (
          <form name="form_name1" id="form_name3">
            form 3
          </form>
        )
      default: return null;
     }
   }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <select value={this.state.selectedValue} onChange={this.handleChange}>
            <option value="form_name1">Form 1</option>
            <option value="form_name2">Form 2</option>
            <option value="form_name3">Form 3</option>
          </select>
        </form>
        {this.renderSelectedForm(this.state.selectedValue)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here's in action: https://codepen.io/herodrigues/pen/XOBLVb

Answer (score 1):

Your `display` is set to 'none'.

Answer (score 1):

```
handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ selectedValue: event.target.value   });
}
```

You either need to make a constructor that binds `this` for the `handleChange` function or just declare it in the way above, which auto-binds.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap  inside `()`. Like below

```
switch(param) {
     case 'form_name1':
     return (<form name="form_name1" id="form_name1" style={formStyle}>
     form 1
     </form>);                        
     ...
}
```

Comment: That's not solving it - I currently have Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Comment: @MaxT use arrow functions to fix that.